# Firebase Facebook Login with Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am making an Ionic 2 project with Firebase 3 JS SDK.

I have a problem when trying to log in with facebook using the firebase FacebookAuthProvider.

When I try to get the `AuthCredential` from the `FacebookAuthProvider` using

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
let credential = provider.credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
```

At the provider.credential it says `provider.credential` is not a function.

Here is my full SerivceProvider function:

```
loginUserFacebook() {
Facebook.login(['email'])
.then(
  (response) => {
    let credential: firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
    credential = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider().credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
    this.fireAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
)
.catch(
  (error) => {
    var errorMessage: string = error.message;
    let prompt = Alert.create({
      message: errorMessage,
      buttons: [{text: "Ok"}]
    });

    this.nav.present(prompt);
  }
);
```

}

I am importing `import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';` 

and have installed the `cordova-plugin-facebook4`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a javascript static method. Change to:

```
let credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
```

Comment: When I use it as a static method and try to compile with `ionic run android`
the following erro shows up while compiling the auth-data.ts file:
`Error TS2339: Property 'credential' does not exist on type 'typeof FacebookAuthProvider'.
[20:41:51] Finished 'build' after 3.31 s`

Comment: Actually, this is a bug in the typescript definitions. The Firebase team has been notified and is working on a fix. In the meantime use the following workaround:

(<any> firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider).credential

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a bug in the `typescript definitions`. The `Firebase` team has been notified and is working on a fix. In the meantime use the following workaround:---

```
(<any> firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider).credential
```